# Clear liquid leaking from used A/C compressor I bought. Should I worry?

Tags: ac, leak, compressor

I recently bought a used A/C compressor to replace the one that died in my 2007 Mazda 3. When I went to the auto wreckers to pick it up, it leaked a clear looking oily liquid out of the one of the screws on the corners that I assume are used to fasten the compressor to the car. The guy I bought it from said that's not a big deal and that he tested it and it works fine.

When I was leaving more of the liquid leaked out of it and onto my clothes. I rotated it so the liquid wouldn't continue to leak out, but it seems like there was more that could come out, so I want to know if I should be concerned. Should I return it, or should it be fine after its installed?

See photos of the compressor below

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It sounds like compressor oil (usually PAG oil of one sort of another). I'm not an AC person, but I don't think I'd worry about it too much ... other than you should replace it with fresh oil.

Comment: Thanks Paul. If it's leaking now though, wouldn't it continue to leak after I put fresh oil, or is it probably just because a screw is loose or something?

Comment: Please tell me the compressor's model and brand so that i can have a look myself. Even better, post pictures of it and the liquid and screws you're referring to. Anyway, if that clear oily liquid (PAG refrigerant lubricant, often laced with a green UV dye so that any leak shows up better) isn't coming from either the refrigerant ports (which, on a side note, should be sealed right after recovering the compressor from the vehicle and checking its functionality) or an oil drain plug, that compressor is bad (it may have a leaking gasket or shaft seal, for example).

Comment: OK I'll take some pics this evening after work. The guy at the parts place rotated the clutch with his hand to show me that it was "good" because there was some resistance there. Not sure if that means anything.

Comment: It doesn't mean a lot. Yes, the clutch hub of an healthy compressor, or at least one with healthy internals, is supposed to rotate smoothly with moderate uniform resistance (to understand what i mean with moderate uniform resistance: with my Delphi CVC, i can rotate its clutch hub with my little finger). The internals may still be good enough to not show any rough spot or seizure, but you can still have a leaking gasket or seal and in that case need to replace it before installing your compressor and having everything leak tested.

Comment: OK, pics added. The oil was leaking out of the hole for one of the big screws sticking out of the corners. I don't remember which one, and the leak was gone when I took the photos, as it had all leaked out into the bag I put it in by then.

Comment: If you'll refill it, refill it with an oil matching the characteristics (chemistry and viscosity) of ATMOS-GU10 (personally, i don't know them; look for them online). Then seal the ports, rotate the compressor around and carefully watch for where the oil leaks from. Properly dispose of any oil, obviously. The body, however, looks rusted and the rust may have damaged a body gasket.

Comment: First, i see open refrigerant ports (the two holes in the second pic) and that's very bad because, aside from not letting you know where exactly the oil came from, the refrigerant oil is hygroscopic. Secondly, the liquid is clearly refrigerant oil because the droplet in the last pic on the right corner shows a green tint. Thirdly, i hope you kept the refrigerant ports upright when you took the compressor with you, if so you clearly have a leaking gasket. Otherwise, the only way to know where it came from is draining the remaining oil, thoroughly cleaning the compressor body and refilling it

Comment: So I took it to the mechanic and told him that some oil leaked out, and he poured some back in and installed it, and it appears to be working.
The only thing is that it's always on, even though the A/C switch isn't engaged. Could that be because of the leak I saw before?

Comment: Highly doubt leaking oil would make a compressor stay on. Have you got the defroster on or the air distribution knob in the defrost position?

Comment: No nothing like that. The compressor was rusted up and the mechanic had to work on it for a while to get it to work so maybe that's why.